# Vite build error: Parse error with PNG image import in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

Im having a problem during building my app. I have a line:

```
<img
            class="h-full w-full object-cover"
            src="../assets/img/loginSignUpForms/Login.PNG"
            alt=""
          />
```

and then i get a strange error msg:

```
1: �PNG
2: →
IHDR♥▬♥♠��1Z☺sRGB��∟�♦gAMA��♂�a♣        pHYs♫�♫�☺�o�d��IDATx^���m�Q��s⌂5�M#����}E▲e�w☻�K ��...
                                                                                                            ^
4: A:�`���♫���?s����c}��♣����o������Xҍ��F|��- W▲��:��‼_��ϗp�<⌂�����g�ܦ~�♂x��↨<☺��d�‼��d�>:�qyd♥.→Y�9�l�+� ?��҅?����...
2�3~�_��⌂�[... ∟↔▲0♂ׄhMX♂�d�h��$�iaX�p�▬�E�♥§�D�ҺL�_��{����oqU♦�G}��▬C��%7u�⌂rm<����ՃQ|>
error during build:
Error: Parse error @:3:106
    at parse$e (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/JSQuizz/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:16497:355)
    at Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/gofrf/Desktop/JSQuizz/client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-52909643.js:46653:27)
```

I read to move a img to public dir in a project so the img can look like:

```
 <div name="left" class="w-[100%] lg:w-[50%]">
          <img class="h-full w-full object-cover" src="/Login.PNG" alt="" />
        </div>
```

but now i get diffrent error msg:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/Login.PNG" from "C:/Users/user/Desktop/JSQuizz/client/src/views/LoginAndSignIn.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/Login.PNG" from "C:/Users/gofrf/Desktop/JSQuizz/client/src/views/LoginAndSignIn.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error stating

Error: Parse error @:3:726
at parse$e (file:///C:/Users/SuperJo/Desktop/building%20website/node_modules/vitepress/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-64acfab2.js:16378:355)
at Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/SuperJo/Desktop/building%20website/node_modules/vitepress/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-64acfab2.js:46247:27)

I just changed the PNG to jpg image and it worked.

IDK why, but it works now.